# Hydra http-post-form based on length of the response

Tags: password-cracking, brute-force, hydra

Is there any way for hydra to understand the correct combination `^USER^` and `^PASS^` in a http-post-form authentication attack based on the length of the body response?

In Burpsuite you can look at the length and understand password and username.[image: For username jack, the found password is 12345678 based on the different length of the response]

So basically how can I set up hydra to look at the length parameter during a http-post-form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible to do with Hydra, but I would recommend using [ffuf](https://github.com/ffuf/ffuf) for this.

You can do an HTTP-POST form bruteforce based on length like this:

```
ffuf -w /path/to/wordlist.txt -X POST -d "username=admin\&password=FUZZ" -u https://target/login.php -fl 480
```

`-fl`: tells it to filter out the length you don't want (failed attempt)
`FUZZ`: is where it will replace words from the wordlist in the request

Although in this approach the username would be static. A little bash scripting hack would solve that.